# nHibernate self referencing table fetch many

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have a self-referencing table which I use to build my tree view.

I use the following query to get the right structure:

```
  public IList<TreeNode> GetAllTreeNodes(string userid)
    {
        var query = Session.Query<TreeNode>()
                   .FetchMany(x => x.Children)
                   .Where(tn => (tn.User.Id == userid) && tn.IsDeleted == false);

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

The only problem with that is that my query ignores the IsDeleted flag of my children collection.

How can I tell NHibernate to query all my not deleted items and their corresponding not deleted children?

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

You can define, per entity or per collection, a WHERE restriction, for example, "WHERE IS_DELETED = 0". See http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2013/03/21/soft-deletes-with-nhibernate.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for response! Wasn't aware that something like that exists... Going to investigate that ...